# require.js alternative way to require?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

New to require.js. I have this:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/sidebar',
    'views/dashboard',
    'views/users',
    'views/venues',
    'views/payments'
], function($, _, Backbone, SidebarView, DashboardView, UsersView, VenuesView, PaymentsView) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '/dashboard': 'showDashboard',
            '/users': 'showUsers',
            '/venues': 'showVenues',
            '/payments': 'showPayments'
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var router = new Router();
        Backbone.history.start();
    }

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

I am wondering if there's an alternative way to write this so I don't have this long line:

```
function($, _, Backbone, SidebarView, DashboardView, UsersView, VenuesView, PaymentsView)
```

Comment: @sabotero why does that matteR? lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AMD sugar:

```
define(function(require) {

  var $ = require('jquery')
    , _ = require('underscore')
    , Backbone = require('backbone')

    // etc...
```

I personally prefer this because it’s closer to CommonJS syntax, but there are some browser limitations (it requires `Function.prototype.toString`) so make sure you pack it using `r.js` before production.

More examples in the docs: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html#sugar

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try more generic and natural solution (not only for JS) http://sourceforge.net/projects/minimerge

It supports full dependencies stack, multiple source trees and is purely java based (and you can use it for content filtering too).

Particulary you end up with:

//:include com/package/Class.js

//any code.

Answer (score 0):

minimerge is a plain java tool, few KB small and super fast. I use it for my html5 web projects.
It also does CSS with dependencies and any text based files ;-)