# Require js, how to call defined module?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to define a module in `requirejs` and use it in another script.
I've tried a lot of things, but I cannot achieve what I want.

At the moment this is what I have.

```
define([],{
    return {
        functionOne: function(){etc, etc...}
        functionTwo: function(){etc, etc...}        
    }
})
```

Then I put this in the configuration file:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {myModule: pathToMyModule}
})
```

And then, this in the script where I want to use this module

```
requirejs(["myModule"], function(){
    //Some code    
})
```

But I'm still getting this errors when I try to use the defined module:

```
myModule is not defined.
functionOne is not defined.    
functionTwo is not defined.
```

Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't your define code have a name.

Comment: @Sauryabhatt I think you can [omit the name](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define) to use the file name as your module's name. Although, the define call doesn't look syntactically correct. It should be `define([], function () { ... });`.

Comment: Sorry about the comma, but i put it right in the actual code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare your module, you need to use a `function`, so the first line in `myModule.js` should look like this:

```
define([], function () { // ...
```

When you're invoking the module, you need to declare it as an argument, so your `requirejs` call should look like this:

```
requirejs(["myModule"], function (myModule) {
//                                ^^^^^^^^
// Notice the argument declaration
```

The following worked for me:

```
// myModule.js
define([], function () {
    return {
        functionOne: function(){
            console.log("Hello, world. I'm functionOne.");
        },
        functionTwo: function(){
            console.log("Hello, world. I'm functionTwo.");
        }        
    }
});

// require.config.js
requirejs.config({
    paths: { myModule: './myModule' }
});

// index.js
requirejs(["myModule"], function (myModule) {
    myModule.functionOne();
    myModule.functionTwo();
})
```

Comment: Nice!, this one works. But i have a big list of dependencies in my ascript.
Is there any way to remove all the dependencies from the parameters?
Thanks.

Comment: @Albeo There are other alternatives involving a wrapper module or the `arguments` variable, please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20284265/824495) for more details.

Comment: @Albeo please feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate a little more to make it more readable, but it works.

Comment: This is the exact explanation, I was looking for :)